# When I enter the django shell, why does it 'freeze' the database

Tags: python, django

Why does the database remain static when a user enters the django shell via `python manage.py runserver`? For example:

```
>>> from userprofile.models import UserProfile
>>> up=UserProfile.objects.get(id=4)
>>> up.get_jobs_applied_for()
[<JobApplication: david - Editor>, <JobApplication: david - Assistant Director>]
# delete entries in the mysql database
>>> up.get_jobs_applied_for()
[<JobApplication: david - Editor>, <JobApplication: david - Assistant Director>]
# but the results do not reflect that
```

And the method being called:

```
# in `UserProfile` class
def get_jobs_applied_for(self):
    jobs_applied_for = self.jobapplication_set.order_by('-timestamp')
    return jobs_applied_for
```

Why doesn't it query the db in real-time?

Comment: How is that method implemented?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just that your UserProfile instance is caching the jobs_applied_for? Try doing up=UserProfile.objects.get(id=4) again after deleting your entries from the mysql database.

Comment: @Iain Yeah, same thing. Even if I start at the top with re-importing the UserProfile model.

Comment: Is your deletion running in a separate transaction, and that isn't being committed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Django only populates a QuerySet the first time you do something that requires that the query be executed; after that, it keeps the same result set in memory. The order_by() doesn't force another query to be executed against the database.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you please provide a link to where that is in the documentation, or where i could read more about it?

Comment: This is incorrect, Django caches evaluated `QuerySet`. The `up.get_jobs_applied_for()` lines just call `jobs_applied_for.__repr__()`, which only evaluate something like `jobs_applied_for[:20]` instead of the `jobs_applied_for`. @David542

Comment: I believe that's what I said, but I'll agree that "caching" is better description than "populating."

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew Schinckel asked, where and when does the deletion occur? If it occurs in another process, before the second `>>> up.get_jobs_applied_for()`, and you're using MySQL w/ isolation level set to [`REPEATABLE READ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html), the MySQL DB would provide you an earlier snapshot before the deletion. (Providing that the code in your question are running in a whole transaction, for example in managed transaction or on some MySQL connection pool)

Also, you could use `django.db.connection.queries` between lines to confirm whether Django tries to query from DB actually.